# Issue with the NVIDIA-SMI process display

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I am not able to see the process in whether using GPU or not. I see only Memory usage but not the process listed in the monitoring panel.
After typing `nvidia-smi` I see this:

```
# nvidia-smi
Tue Jul 11 12:07:49 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 730      Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 64%   70C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    673MiB /  4040MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GT 730      Off  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   40C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    250MiB /  4043MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GT 730      Off  | 0000:06:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 37%   52C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    251MiB /  4043MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
|    1                  Not Supported                                         |
|    2                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to reset the GPU using the following command:

```
sudo nvidia-smi --gpu-reset -i 0
```

But it doesn't work.

Kindly help me as I am out of idea. Here is the NVCC output

```
# nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and have found people say that its a pro card feature only.
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/697308/cuda-setup-and-installation/compute-processes-not-supported/ Some people suggest this fix, but it looks out of date:
https://github.com/CFSworks/nvml_fix